# Inserting items into a 2D array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array

I am working on solving an algorithm (do not want to explain my approach, as I am still trying to solve it on my own). However I am having difficulty with a particular part.

```
function smallestCommons(arr)
{
  var rangeArray = [];
  var outterArray = [];
  var testArray = [];

  arr = arr.sort(function(a,b){return a>b});

  for(var i=arr[0];i<=arr[1];i++)
  {
    rangeArray.push(i);
  }
  for(var j=0;j<rangeArray.length;j++)
  {
    for(var k=1;k<=100;k++)
    {
      if(k%rangeArray[j] === 0)
      {
        outterArray.push([k]);
      }
    }
  } 
  console.log(outterArray);
}

smallestCommons([1,5]);
```

The second part of the code I am looping through the items in rangeArray [1,2,3,4,5] and trying to insert all the multiples (from 1 to 100) of EACH index into a DIFFERENT array. But my code currently is pushing EACH individual number which is a multiple into its own array per each digit. I need it to push all the multiples of each index of rangeArray into outer array. So that I end up with a 2D array of all the multiples of rangeArray in different array for every iteration of j.

So for example instead of ending up with

```
outerArray == [[1],[2],[3]...]
```

I would end up with all the multiples of 1 (up to 100) into one array and then all the multiples of 2 into another array and so on and so forth so it looks like this.

```
outerArray == [[1,2,3,4...] [2,4,6,8...] [3,6,9,12...]]
```

Its very hard to explain, hopefully I have been clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite impossible to understand your question, but wisely you've described the output you're trying to generate...

Turns out, that's quite simple:

```js
let arr = [];
for(let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
  let innerArr = [];
  for(let j = i; j <= 100; j += i) {
    innerArr.push(j);
  }
  arr.push(innerArr);
}

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Thanks this helped. Is there any particular reason for using let instead of var?

Comment: @mattHunting10 - rule of thumb, never use `var`, it's effectively obsolete.

Comment: Really?? Can you please explain, I had no idea.

Comment: @mattHunting10 - that's too broad and broadly covered. Read about `let`...

Answer (score 0):

how many elements should be in each multiple array? I guessed 100 but you can adjust that accordingly...

```js
function smallestCommons(arr)
{
  var rangeArray = [];
  var outterArray = [];
  var testArray = [];

  arr = arr.sort(function(a,b){return a>b});

  for(var i=arr[0];i<=arr[1];i++)
  {
    rangeArray.push(i);
  }
  for(var j=0;j<rangeArray.length;j++)
  {
    for(var k=1;k<=100;k++)
    {
      if(k%rangeArray[j] === 0)
      {
        var multipleArray = [];
        for(var z=1;z<100;z++) {
          multipleArray.push(z*k);
          }
        outterArray.push(multipleArray);
      }
    }
  } 
  console.log(outterArray);
}

smallestCommons([1,5]);
```